# Sequelize inside GraphQL doesn't join junction table

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, graphql

I have the following tables:

**users**

- id
- name
- email

**users_categories_data**

- id
- label

**users_categories (junction table)**

- id
- user_id
- cat_id

A user can only have one category. I'm trying to query the category inside the user in GraphQL so that I can get the category label and id as a result directly:

```
{
  users(id: 6988) {
    email

    category {
      id
      label 
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the associations:

**USER**

```
associate(models) {
  this.hasOne(models.userCategoryData, {
    through: models.userCategory,
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
  });
}
```

**UserCategoriesData**

```
associate: (models) => {
  UserCategoryData.belongsToMany(models.user, {
    through: models.userCategory,
    foreignKey: 'cat_id',
  });
}
```

**UserCategory (junction table)**

```
associate: (models) => {
  UserCategory.belongsTo(models.user, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
  UserCategory.belongsTo(models.userCategoryData, { foreignKey: 'cat_id' });
},
```

This creates the `getUserCategoryDatum()` function in the resolve function of my user's GraphQL Type. When I run it, I get the following queries:

```
SELECT `id`, `email`, `name` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`id` = 6988 ORDER BY `user`.`id` ASC;
SELECT `id`, `label`, `user_id` FROM `users_categories_data` AS `userCategoryData` WHERE `userCategoryData`.`user_id` IN (6988);
```

Obviously, this is not correct, as `users_categories_data` table doesn't have `user_id`. The query should do an extra join and get the `cat_id` from the junction table and then query `users_categories_data` using `WHERE userCategoryData.id = cat_id`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `HasOne` relations aren't usually modelled with a join table. Do you need this join table ?

Comment: Changing `hasOne` to `belongsToMany` worked. But what if I wanted to have a unique constraint on the junction table for `user_id`? Should I still be using `belongsToMany` then?

Comment: No, you should not. BelongsToMany is a relation defined as Users have many categories, and Categories have many Users. In your case, e.g. Users belongs to one Category, and Category have many Users, you should add a `category_id` to the `Users` table and create `User.belongsTo(Category)` relation. This way, you are expressing your constraint: a User belongs to a Category and only one.

Comment: That's how I would have created the db structure, but I was told that we had to future proof it in case PO wanted users to select multiple categories. I'm sticking to `belongsToMany` then. I also used `as: 'userCategory'`, so that it wouldn't pluralize the generated function. Please submit your answer and I'll approve it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: great! doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BelongsToMany is a relation defined as Users have many categories, and Categories have many Users.

In your case, e.g. Users belongs to one Category, and Category have many Users, you should add a `category_id` to the `Users` table and create `User.belongsTo(Category)` relation.
This way, you are expressing your constraint: a User belongs to a Category and only one.